# Toggle the top parent <div> from the child element using jquery

Tags: jquery

Problem:-

```
<div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <select id="s1">
           .................
     </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

I want to toggle the first div, starting from element s1. I can do in this manner:-

```
$('#s1').parent().parent().parent().toggle(false);
```

But is there any way i can get to the parent div directly with some shortcut. Is there any way i can avoid using parent() method 3 times ?

Pls suggest.

Comment: Can you give the `div` in question some sort of identifier? (an `id`, a `class`, any attribute that the `div` elements inside it don't have?)

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing as James :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#s1').parents('div').last();
```

This will give you the topmost parent div of your select element.
Alternatively there's the parentsUntil method, which can be used like so:

```
$('#s1').parentsUntil(':not(div)');
```

Comment: but last() will give me the last div, i need the top parent div. OR it means that it is starting the traversal from s1 and the last is considered as the first div in this case. Pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The last div will be the topmost parent div - the elements are returned in order from the closest parent to the outer ones. See http://api.jquery.com/parents/ for documentation

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent some sort of classname or an id, and use that:

```
$('#s1').parent('.parent').toggle(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#s1').parents('div').last().toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way is putting an "id" or a "class"

HTML

```
<div class="thisdiv">
    <div>
      <div>
        <select id="s1">
           .................
     </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#s1').parents('.thisdiv').toggle(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your HTML you could do something like this -

HTML

```
<div class="top">
    <div>
      <div>
          <input type="button" value="c" id="s1"/>
           .................
     </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

jQuery -

```
$('#s1').closest('.top').toggle(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `.parents()`(http://api.jquery.com/parents/) availaible, which selects all the ancestors up to the document root (excluded) of the elements in your selector

But again, without anything to filter them... I don't know if it will help